# What is the purpose of macros with special bit-wise operations?

Tags: c

In some code, I find macros defined like this.

```
#define M_COUNT (1<<0)
```

How are they used?

Comment: Do you find a usage of `M_COUNT` in the code?

Comment: Without the larger context, the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Macros like that are used to give a name (and thus meaning) to bit-masks.

Bit-fiddling code can be hard to follow, so adding macros that represent often occurring pieces of code can help a lot.